# Errno 13 Permission denied: 'Text.txt'

Tags: python, scripting, error

So i've found out, that you get this error when opening a blend file through the "last opened" part.

When I open the blend file directly, the error does not appear.

Is there a reason behind it? The folder and file are readable and writeable and i am logged as admin.

Open Blender -> select .blend file from last sessions -> run script -> error

Open .blend file from folder -> run script -> no error

Comment: Hello, are you sure the 2 blend files point to the same directory when you open them using the 2 different methods ?

Comment: Yes, I made sure of that too. Same file, and all other files are in the same folder directory aswell.

Comment: Is there something in the console when you go to Window > toggle System Console ?

Comment: Only the normal "Errno 13 Permission denied" message. Nothing specific. As I did not have permission to write into the folder